# Read RGBA values of pixel from surface/texture with SDL2?

Tags: pascal, sdl-2

How do I read the RGBA values of a specific pixel, at given coordinates x and y, from a surface or texture with SDL2 in Free Pascal?

Comment: `SDL_RenderReadPixels()`

Comment: Yes, and from this how do I extract the RGBA values exactly? SDL_RenderReadPixels will read pixels from a surface and copy them onto a target texture, that's all. By itself it won't give me the RGBA values of a pixel (or rectangle in the case of SDL_RenderReadPixels).

Comment: You are incorrect. It writes the value to `void* pixels`. Allocate 32-bits as `uint8_t pixels[4];` and call `SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, &r, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32, &pixels, 1);` where `const SDL_Rect r = {x, y, 1, 1};` then `pixels[0]` is the red value and `pixels[3]` is alpha, etc. (But in Pascal not C)

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels doesn't even contain the word "texture"!

Comment: Got it working thanks.

Comment: @seb0029 do not edit your solution into your question-post it as an answer if you feel it us worth sharing.

Comment: @LegendofPedro To be fair the op did say '**surface** *or texture*' so although true it doesn't apply for texture it does for surface.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
    spriteSheetTexture: PSDL_texture;
    pixel: ^UInt8;
    pixelCnt: byte;
    SDLRect: TSDL_rect;

spriteSheetSurface:=SDL_loadBMP(PChar('spr4\sprite sheets\spr'+fVal(spriteSheetNum)+'.spr'));
SDLRect.x:=0; SDLRect.y:=0; SDLRect.w:=1; SDLRect.h:=1;
SDL_renderReadPixels(SDLRenderer, @SDLRect, 0, pixel, spriteSheetSurface^.pitch);
for pixelCnt:=0 to 3 do
    writeLn(pixel[pixelCnt]);
```

Actually it doesn't seem to work. Pixel returns zero for every index, no matter what pixel I read.

I was right when I said SDL_RenderReadPixels involves a texure. The SDL 2 documentation alludes to it: "Use this function to read pixels from the current rendering target". The current rendering target being either a texture or SDL screen (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels).

Answer (score 0):

I know, the question is old and i do not know how to code in pascal...

...but if someone is searching for a working solution in c++, here we go:

```
SDL_Color getColorFromPositionOfTexture(SDL_Texture* tex, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    int w, h, format, access;
    SDL_QueryTexture(tex, &format, &access, &w, &h);

    if (x >= w || y >= h) {
        // handle error: x or y is out of bounds
    }

    void* pixels; // Pixeldata
    int pitch; // Length of a row

    SDL_LockTexture(tex, NULL, &pixels, &pitch); // Fill variables

    Uint32* pixelData = (Uint32*)pixels;
    Uint32 pixel = pixelData[y * (pitch / 4) + x];

    SDL_UnlockTexture(tex);

    SDL_Color color;
    SDL_PixelFormat* pixelFormat = SDL_AllocFormat(format);

    SDL_GetRGB(pixel, pixelFormat, &color.r, &color.g, &color.b);
    color.a = SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE;
    SDL_FreeFormat(pixelFormat);

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Before posting your answer, check if a similar one has been asked for C++. If not, consider creating a community wiki by asking and answering your own question. This helps keep information organized and increases the chances of others finding your solution when they need it.